# Confirmation modal for flask not working in a loop

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

My program lists a set of users that can be deleted. And upon deleting, there'll be a confirmation modal before it deletes the user.

The deleting part of the code works, but I have problem with the modal itself because it's the one that passes of the data in the deleting users function.

My html loops the users and it's set of roles. Don't mind the roles, for I'm only concerned with the confirmation modal. :)

Eg:

x user1
x user2
x user3 (This is the one that I'll delete)

When I delete user3, it deletes user1. The results were:

x user2
x user3

Here's the code of my HTML. The modal is already included.

```
<div class="col-md-10">


            {% for u in all_users %}

              <td>
              <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><img src = "{{url_for('static', filename='assets/images/x.png') }}"></a> 
              <!-- <a href="{{url_for('Users.delete_users', user=u.username)}}" " ><img src = "{{url_for('static', filename='assets/images/check.png') }}"></a> -->
              {{u.username}}
              </td>


              {% for r in roles %}
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{u.username}} {{r.name}}" value="{{r.name}}" 
                {% if r in u.load_roles(u.username) %}
                checked
                {% endif %}
                /></td> 
              {% endfor %}
              </tr>

              {% for u in all_users %}
              <div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">

                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm Selection</h4>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
                            <p class="debug-url"></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <a href="{{url_for('Users.delete_users', user=u.username)}}" class="btn btn-danger" name="button">Proceed</a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}

            {% endfor %}

            <input class="btn btn-primary" button type="submit" name="button" value="Save Roles"></input><br>
        </form>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: can u add your view function?
by the way, you can't use div as a child of <table> or <tr>. 
using div inside <td> is fine. 
and you have some end tags (</tr>, </form>, </tbody>, </table>), which I cant find their beginning tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems. The first problem is that you create each set of modals for each user. Move one of the `{% endfor %}` tags up under the first loop through the users.

Second, you reuse the `id` attribute for each modal. `id`s must be unique. You should use something like

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete-{{ u.id }}"><img src = "{{url_for('static', filename='assets/images/x.png') }}"></a>
```

in your first loop through the users, and then

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete{{ u.id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

in the second.